# Can't create Quick Action or Button in ActionPlanTemplate object

Tags: button, quickaction

I've been struggling with creating an Action/Button or Link in ActionPlanTemplate object.

I have access to all permissions I could find on internet:

1. Permission Set Assignment: Action Plans
2. Permission Set License Assignments: Action Plans
3. ActionPlan/ActionPlanTemplate/RecurrenceSchedule Object Settings: Read, Create, Edit, Delete, View All, Modify All

When I try to create an Action or Button/Link i get this message:

> Validation Errors While Saving Record(s) There were custom validation
> error(s) encountered while saving the affected record(s). The first
> validation error encountered was "Object Name: bad value for
> restricted picklist field: ActionPlanTemplate".

> Insufficient Privileges You do not have the level of access necessary
> to perform the operation you requested. Please contact the owner of
> the record or your administrator if access is necessary. For more
> information, see Insufficient Privileges Errors.

Am I missing anything?

---

References:

- https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.fsc_action_plans_admin_standard_features_support.htm&type=5
- https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54S00000DxUN1SAN
- https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.fsc_action_plans_admin_object_permissions.htm&type=5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not anything you're missing - the Object itself (ActionPlanTemplate) doesn't support creating custom actions.

The error message

> Object Name: bad value for restricted picklist field: ActionPlanTemplate"

Is the hint that the entity name of ActionPlanTemplate is not allowed to be used. This isn't an access issue, though - just something internally set on the object. In general, this entity isn't allowed much editing by the customer - as you can also see that it doesn't even support creating custom fields which is denoted with the  `isCustomizable` flag

```
SELECT IsCustomizable,DeveloperName FROM EntityDefinition WHERE DeveloperName = 'ActionPlanTemplate'
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! I was suspecting this would be the case, but I didn't find any reference documents or sources indicating it. Either way, I have created a Salesforce support case in order to confirm it officially! Thanks again, I'll mark it as best answer :)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that wants an official SFDC response regarding this problem, I have created a Salesforce support case and they've answered that it is not possible to create Action/Button or Link in this object, as mentioned by @Kris Goncalves.

Here it is their official response to this problem:

> After thorough investigation and analysis, I regret to inform you that the requested functionality is not feasible within the current capabilities of Salesforce. I understand that this news may be disappointing, and I want to express my sincere apologies for any inconvenience this may cause.
>
> Please know that we explored various avenues and considered all possible solutions to meet your requirements. However, due to technical limitations and constraints within the Salesforce platform, implementing the requested functionality is not within our current capabilities. Salesforce has published an article about the possibilities and limitations of action plans here: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.fsc_action_plans_admin_setup.htm&type=5